# Show all data in a single object instead of nested object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize ORM and for DB I am using MySQL, in which I have associated two tables and getting the data, but I want 2nd data (another table's data) should not come in like nested object instead could we show all data in a single object (both table data).

let me show the screen shot.

[image]

What I want to something like.

[image]

Ignore the keys and values of data, but my question here, could we here show the data of another table (think like inner join) in the same object, not something like in nested object.

Any suggestion would be appreciable thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly want but according to your input/output I think you want to flatten the nested object(?) and for that you can use the next piece of code-

```
nested_obj = {"message": "Hey you", "nested_obj": {"id": 1}}

flattened_obj = Object.assign(
    {}, 
    ...function _flatten(o) { 
      return [].concat(...Object.keys(o)
        .map(k => 
          typeof o[k] === 'object' ?
            _flatten(o[k]) : 
            ({[k]: o[k]})
        )
      );
    }(nested_obj)
  )

console.log(JSON.stringify(flattened_obj));
```